# Option to create north arrow missing in QGIS map layout (v 3.4.3)

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, print-composer, north-arrow

I am giving a QGIS course. Both of my students, working with QGIS version 3.4.3 (Madeira), do not have the option to add a north arrow to their map canvas in the map layout. I cannot figure out why this is the case, and online I am not able to find any guidance whatsoever. Why is this option missing, and how can I enable it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

North arrows in older versions of qgis are added as SVG grafik and then set the rotate (sync) option

[image]

Comment: Indeed, i thought it was already there in 3.4. But the doc proves me wrong: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/forest_maps.html?highlight=north%20arrow